# Converting Σ i(i + 1) into a formula, given this hint

Tags: summation

The given summation is: $$\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)$$

The goal is to convert it into a formula which only uses *n*.

Solving this, I got the answer:

$$\frac{n}{3}(n+1)(n+2)$$

However, I don't believe the way I solved it is the intended method, despite arriving at the correct solution. This is because a hint is provided:

$$i(i+1) = \frac{(i+1)^3 - i^3 - 1}{3}$$

My solution did not benefit from this hint, thus I believe my method of solving was unintended.

Based on the hint, what method should be used to convert the summation into a formula?

Comment: There's a typo in the hint: the fraction should be $\;\dfrac{(i+\color{red}1)^3-i^3-1}3$.

Comment: The hint suggests an obvious telescope structure.

Comment: Using the hint, the evaluation of the sum ultimately boils down to determining $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \big[(i+1)^3-i^3\big]$, which can be easily seen to equal 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{#C00}{(1+1)}^3&-&1^3 \\
\color{darkorange}{(2+1)}^3&-&\color{#C00}2^3 \\
\color{green}{(3+1)}^3&-&\color{darkorange}3^3 \\
&\vdots& \\
\color{brown}{(n)}^3&-&\color{royalblue}{(n-1)}^3 \\
(n+1)^3&-&\color{brown}n^3 \\ \hline \text{What's left?}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: BTW, what method did you use?  It's probably valid and maybe even obliquely used the hint.

Comment: The typo was corrected. Thanks for pointing that out.

@fleablood: I just accepted the top-voted answer, and the second approach given there is the one I used. It struck me as being more obvious, given "i^2 + i", and I didn't see how changing it into that massive alternative helped.

The answers really helped clarify things. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $i$,

$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(i+1)^3-i^3-1}{3}&=&\frac{i^3+3i^2+3i+1-i^3-1}{3}\\
&=&\frac{3i^2+3i}{3}\\
&=&i(i+1)
\end{eqnarray}$

So

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)&=&\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(i+1)^3-i^3-1}{3}\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^n[(i+1)^3-i^3-1]\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)^3-\sum_{i=1}^ni^3-\sum_{i=1}^n1\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i^3-\sum_{i=2}^ni^3-1-\sum_{i=1}^n1\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}((n+1)^3-1-n)\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}(n^3+3n^2+2n)\\
&=&\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}
\end{eqnarray}$

Another approach is

$\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+i=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and simplifies.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+ 1) = \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(i+1)^3-i^3-1}3=$

$1/3[\sum_{k=1}^n (i+1)^3- \sum_{k=1}^n i^3 - \sum_{k=1}^n1]=$

$1/3[\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} i^3- \sum_{k=1}^n i^3 - n]=$

$1/3[(n+1)^3- 1^3 - n]=$

$1/3[n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n - n]=$

$1/3[n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n]=$

$n/3[n^2 + 3n + 2]=$

$\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)} 3$

Answer (score 1):

The hint is incorrect, as you can easily tell by epanding the RHS.  They probably meant
$$i(i+1)=\frac{(i+1)^3-i^3-1}{3}\ ,$$
and you can use this to evaluate the result as a telescoping sum:
$$\eqalign{\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)
  &=\frac13\sum_{i=1}^n((i+1)^3-i^3-1)\cr
  &=\frac13((2^3+\cdots+n^3+(n+1)^3)-(1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3)-(1+2+\cdots+n))\cr
  &=\frac13((n+1)^3-1-\frac12n(n+1))\cr}$$
and so on.