# How can I find the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{10} i(i+1)$?

Tags: summation

During the resolution of a physics problem, I have encountered the sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} i(i+1)$$

For practical purposes, I evaluated it using a Python script, but a calculator would have been enough since the sum stops at $i=10$. However, I wonder what I could do mathematically with that sum if I did not have access to a computer and the sum reached large values of $i$.

Is there a way to evaluate it analytically?

Comment: It breaks up into sums of $i^2$ and $i$, each of which has its own closed-form solution.

Comment: @WillJagy what does the Hockey-stick identity have to do with my problem? I don't quite get it...

Comment: The thing you are adding up is double the binomial coefficient $i+1$  choose 2

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780162/induction-problem-a-formula-for-sum-i-1n-ii1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632433/converting-%ce%a3-ii-1-into-a-formula-given-this-hint), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850284/how-can-simplify-this-summation-notation), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916505/want-help-for-prove-formula-by-combinatoric-argument-1-cdot-22-cdot-33-cdot-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $$(i+1)^3 - i^3 - 1 = i^3 + 3i^2 + 3i + 1 - i^3 - 1 = 3(i^2 + i) = 3i(i+1).$$  Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1) &= \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^n \left((i+1)^3 - i^3 - 1\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (i+1)^3 - \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 - \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left(\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} i^3 - \sum_{i=1}^n i^3\right) - \frac{n}{3} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left((n+1)^3 - 1^3 - n\right) \\
&= \frac{n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n}{3} \\
&= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is the formula
$$
\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)=\frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2),
$$
which you can prove by mathematical induction.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, does that formula happen to have a name?

Comment: @WildFeather   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: and the sum is double the binomial coefficient $(n+2) $ choose 3

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n x^{i+1} = x\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n i(i+1)x^{i-1} = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}x\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n i(i+1) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}x\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \; at\; x=1. $$

Comment: Wow, this is a very cute, nice Idea.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$(i+1)^3-i^3=3i^2+3i+1\\=3i(i+1)+1$$ Thus$$\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)={1\over 3}\sum_{i=1}^n[(i+1)^3-i^3]+{1\over 3}n\\ ={1\over 3}[(n+1)^3-1]+{1\over 3}n$$